# Computing with Landau symbols

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

I want to find values for constants $C,D$ so that
$$
e^{cosh(h)-1}+\frac{1}{C}+\frac{h^2}{D}=O(h^4)
$$
holds.

I know that by definition, for $cosh(h)-1\rightarrow 0$, we have

$$
e^{cosh(h)-1}=1+(cosh(h)-1)+O(cosh(h)-1)^2)
$$
$$
=cosh(h)+O(cosh^2(h)-2cosh(h)+1)
$$
After that, I can see that
$$
\frac{1}{C}+\frac{h^2}{D}=\frac{D+Ch^2}{CD}
$$
but I'm not really sure where to go after that.

Comment: What if you start composing (from inside to outside the Taylor series of $e^{\cosh(h)-1}$ ?

Comment: $$\cosh h=1+\frac{h^2}{2}+\frac{h^2}{4!}+O(h^6)$$
$$e^{\cosh h-1}=e^{\frac{h^2}{2}+\frac{h^2}{4!}+O(h^6)}=1+\Big(\frac{h^2}{2}+\frac{h^2}{4!}+O(h^6)\Big)+\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{h^2}{2}+\frac{h^2}{4!}+O(h^6)\Big)^2+...$$